# Tsung using ejabberd server authentication failure?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, tsung

After start tsung i got log message from ejabberd.log file:

```
I(<0.427.0>:ejabberd_c2s:651) : ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.4407>,<0.426.0>}) Failed authentication for one1@192.155.1.666 from IP 192.155.1.666 ({{192,155,1,666},5
```

Comment: Hi, is not clear what the question is.   Your server is named "192.155.1.666"?. Are you able to login to it on account  "one1" using a normal client?.  Are you sure tsung is using the right password?.

Comment: this is very interesting IP (192.155.1.666). The network straight from hell. Only devil himself could encode 666 on eight bits.

Comment: @user425720 that is not real ip its just a example ip if want just assume 192.168.1.10

Answer (score 0):

Which version you are using?
I am using 2.1.13 with tsung. I have to make this change to make tsung work.

```
diff --git a/src/tsung/ts_jabber_common.erl b/src/tsung/ts_jabber_common.erl
index 95646a0..fecf6bc 100644
--- a/src/tsung/ts_jabber_common.erl
+++ b/src/tsung/ts_jabber_common.erl
@@ -318,7 +318,7 @@ connect(#jabber{domain=Domain, version = Version}) ->
       ts_msg_server:get_id(list),
       "' to='",
       Domain,
-      "' xmlns='jabber:client' ",VersionStr,"xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>"]).
+      "' xmlns='jabber:client' ","xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>"]).
```

And you can find some useful comments [here](http://www.quora.com/ejabberd/Ejabberd-load-test-with-tsung).

Answer (score 0):

See this code, it runs perfectly. If username is abc@reeng you must configure it like this

```
<options>
    <option type="ts_jabber" name="global_number" value="200"></option>
    <option type="ts_jabber" name="userid_max" value="200"></option>
    <option type="ts_jabber" name="domain" value="reeng"></option>
    <option name="file_server" id='userdb' value="/home/sanbox/users.csv" />
</options>
```

Read username, pass in file .csv
http://tutslaptrinh.com/tutorial-detail/tsung-test-connection-ejabberd